# Objective C: loop efficiently through particular range of elements within NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, nsarray

I would like to quickly loop though part of NSArray, for example from position 700 to 950 in array with 1000 objects.

I don't think using [array objectAtIndex:index] is a good approach here, since it's slower than quick iteration using for (Object *obj in array)

What is the best approach in this case? I am considering using

for (Object *obj in [array subarrayWithRange]]) but not sure what the overhead will be, since a subarray will be created for this.

Are there other good options?

Comment: You could try the subarray technique and profile the results?

Comment: Try both and profile. The first approach has lower startup cost, but higher per-item cost, so it's not obvious which is faster in the end. The real question is what kind of code is in the loop body. If the body is heavyweight, then the loop overhead may be a non-issue in either case.

Comment: What makes you think objectAtIndex is that slow?

Comment: Hot Licks, objectAtIndex is about 3-4 times slower than fast enumeration . There are a few articles on this.

Comment: @antonio - But do a couple of calls and you can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:` to enumerate an array at the indexes in an [NSIndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which can be generated from a range.

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(700, 950)];

[array enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet options:kNilOptions usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the overhead from using `subarrayWithRange:` is minimal as it doesn't copy the original array, but just creates a thin wrapper around it and refers back to the original object.

Of course, you'd have to actually profile it and see if it's too high or not.